# Systemd service successful but did not start script

Tags: linux, centos, script, systemd, systemctl

I created a script that has to start on boot. So for this script I created a systemd service and enabled it in systemctl. The script is creating a folder in /mnt, then mounts a cd to it, copies files, unmounts the cd and removes the folder again.

When I execute the script, the script is doing what it should do. But when I execute the service (systemctl start startupscript.service), the service is finishing like it should, but apparently the script is not executed. The service tells me however that it ended succesfully. There is also nothing in the logs that show that anything went wrong.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks!

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/startupscript.service
[Unit]
Description=A random description

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/startup

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the file-system was not yet loaded and the script needed forking.

Problem was solved by adding/changing:

```
[Unit]
After=local-fs.target
[Service]
Type=forking
```